# How to create a view that can identify each person's club out of many club?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm making the database of club's members and I found this problem.

Suppose:

1. There are people who want to join clubs.
2. Let's imagine that there're **10** club.
3. Each **person** choose to join **from 1 to 5 clubs**.
4. Each **club's administrator** have a data of all the person who join his club only.

   (Example: if A join football club then football club's administrator will have his name but he won't know whether A join another club or not.)
5. I have a data of all the people who choose to join clubs.(retrieve from each club's administrator.)

   If A joins 3 clubs that means I have 3 table that have A's name.
6. I have create a table that store the name of each club.

### Questions

If there's not only A but it's 100 person like this, then how can I create one table that have a person's name and all the clubs they join?

Can I create a view table that have a format like this:
personID, personName, club1, club2, club3, club4, club5 (club# can be null.)

OR

personID, personName, allOfClubs

OR

Do I have to manually check on each person?

Comment: Do you have any current code or erd etc?

Comment: If you're having trouble formulating a good question, read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). I can't fully understand what you mean. Sample tables and expected output based on those go a long way of making your problem clear (and give us something to test our answers against)

Comment: Your original title is worthy of downvotes on its own. We're not aiming exactly for a family-oriented experience here, but we want it to be professional. If you are having trouble expressing how to describe things, please do it in a way that does not give volunteer editors more work to do. Please also take the time to learn the formatting tools - using paragraphs and lists in Markdown, you don't need to add HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't store data like that in a database - that is Excel spreadsheet thinking.
You should have at least three tables, possibly four if a club can have more than one administrator.

Your tables should be People, Clubs, Memberships.

Memberships would be a junction table that you store one PersonId, one ClubID, and probably some other information Join date etc.

This way you have a person who is a member of as many clubs as you like.

Comment: Thank you!! I think it works. According to my raw data, this is perfectly fit!<br> Using membership table as a junction help a lot about data redundancy!!

Answer (score 0):

First you need UNION all the club table:

```
 SELECT 'football' as club, person FROM club1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'rugby'    as club, person FROM club2 UNION ALL

 ....
 SELECT 'tennis'   as club, person FROM clubN
```

Then use [PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-an-Access-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752)

Comment: Yours is also good but I found that Minty's answer is much more easier since I know a little about PivotTable(I think it can be use when the data is time sensitive but my raw data is just name and club so i think i don't need it.) It is going well with the normallization method from Minty. 
BTW Thank a lot.

God bless you.

Comment: Yes, I think on Minty solution too. But your question say every team manager only know his data so I thought keeping all the data together wasn't an option if each manager handle his player list separately . Anyway in that format you still will need the PivotTable to show the data in your desire format